# How to access a certain row in a dataset by its name?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have defined a matrix in MATLAB, named M,

```
M = [1,2,3;
     3,2,1]
```

then I assign names to the row and columns with the following codes:

```
dataset({M 'AA','AC','AG'}, ...
              'obsnames', {'AA','AC'})
```

Well, the matrix should like this:

```
     AA    AC    AG
AA    1     2     3 
AC    3     2     1
```

Now, I am trying to specify the second row with the row name, like `M('AA',:)`, but it does not work, so how to do that, could anyone do give me an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `dataset` is not stored under the variable `M`, so you cannot index it using this variable. You need/can assign it to a new variable.

```
D = dataset({M 'AA','AC','AG'},'obsnames', {'AA','AC'})
```

and

```
D('AA',:)
```

will return:

```
ans = 

          AA    AC    AG
    AA    1     2     3
```

... or just use `M` again: `M = dataset({M ...` and then `M('AA',:)`